# PHP-FPM doesn't write to custom error log specified in pool

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-15.10

I've used the [ondrej/php](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) repo to setup some wordpress sites running well on php7, but phpmyadmin won't do anything except a white-screen despite saying it's php7-compatible.

Clearly the solution lies with finding the error that php is throwing, but I can't write anything to the fpm log.

I've followed [PHP-FPM doesn't write to error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677493/php-fpm-doesnt-write-to-error-log) and [php-fpm one error log file per pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819964/php-fpm-one-error-log-file-per-pool) and here's my config based on the answers offered:

php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/phpma.conf

```
user = phpma
group = phpma
listen = /run/php/phpma.sock
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
listen.mode = 0660
catch_workers_output = yes
```

part of /etc/nginx/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/phpma.sock;
access_log   /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin.access.log;
error_log    /var/log/nginx/phpmyadmin.error.log error;
```

phpinfo shows:

```
PHP Version         7.0.7-2+donate.sury.org~wily+1
display_errors      On 
error_log           /var/log/php-fpm.phpma.log
log_errors          On 
log_errors_max_len  1024
```

the nginx access log is being written to just fine and is:

```
-rw-r-----  1 www-data adm         803 May 28 15:16 phpmyadmin.access.log
```

the php7 fpm log for the main www pool is also being written OK:

```
-rw-------  1 root     root              1023 May 28 14:25 php7.0-fpm.log
```

but the php-fpm log I wish to use isn't being written to:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data             0 May 19 10:31 php-fpm.phpma.log
```

I've also tried chowning the log file to be phpma user and group. I've restarted and looked for errors elsewhere but I've drawn a blank. Any ideas? Thanks.